# Finding number of left and right turns for each shortest route

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, network, direction, shortest-path

I have a network dataset for a city. I have, lets say, 200 trips that are made in that city. I constructed the shortest route for the every pair of the trips, and also the actual route travelled by them using the GPS points available. 
I want to include the number of turns, either left or right, for the shortest route as well as observed route for all of the 200 trips.
Is there any tools in network analysis to do this for a large dataset, that doesn't requires a huge labor and time? (I have thousands of trips data so I was looking for a simple tool or function to accomplish this)

---

I tried using the COPY TRAVERSED SOURCE FEATURES tool, as I found that this could give the required result for my purpose. However, the output for the turn feature is empty every time I run this tool. Why the table for the TURN feature is empty? What might be the reason.

Comment: The first problem is solved. As those point layer was in wrong format. I plotted those co-ordinates again and got the shortest route for every O-D pair.  However, i could not figure out the problem of the number of left and right turns in each route yet. Help appreciated.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is enabling directions, saving those out to a file, and counting the number of times the words left or right appear in the directions. If you've solved part of your problem I would suggest **editing** your question using the button at the lower left to remove any extraneous information that no longer applies.

Comment: While enabling directions, at the time of creating the Network Dataset, I got that message, which is added in the above question. Or did you mean to use Direction TOOL from network analyst ?

Comment: The error means it isn't automatically recognizing the field or fields that contain the street names. If you click the directions button you should be able to set the correct field mappings. The directions tool on the toolbar just displays the window. If no route is selected, it gives directions for all routes. This can be saved to a single file, which you could then figure out a script to parse and count word occurrences per route. To solve it with geometry you'd have to write a script that loops through and looks at polar angle between route segments at vertices. No existing tool I know of.

Comment: I found an additional resource - an [Esri GeoNet post](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/50170) from a few years ago where someone was seeking to do the same thing. They also tried the same Copy Traversed Source tool, but discussion indicates it simply doesn't track the info you want. The suggested solution to pursue there was, as I have already suggested here, to use the Directions tool to output a list and parse that file for counts.

Comment: Responding to your comment from the other question here, where it's more relevant. Regarding whether parsing the xml would require 'heavy' coding, I don't really know. The operation seems simple enough - xml, like html, is a container-based layout by which I mean each route should be contained in an identifying tag (`[routeX]more lines including turns[/routeX]`). So you just need to parse the file to count instances of left/right within each route tag. It's probably easy, but I don't know how to do it and such a question would be off-topic here and better on stackoverflow or superuser.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will look for the method on parsing these information from xml files. Otherwise, if I could not do this, I will post a question for that in other relevant forums.

Comment: I think it may be time to heavily revise your question to make clear where you are currently stuck, if that is the case.